# UNION ALL doesn't generate any data in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-query

I am trying to do UNION ALL for three different tables with same DDL structure but the final output is generating zero rows. I have no clue with what's happening in the underlying execution. Could anybody share your thoughts on this? My sample Hive SQL goes as below. Thank you.

```
SET hive.execution.engine=tez;
    SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
    SET hive.qubole.cleanup.partial.data.on.failure=true;
    SET hive.tez.container.size=8192;
    SET tez.task.resource.memory.mb=8192;
    SET tez.task.resource.cpu.vcores=2;
    SET hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
    SET hive.qubole.dynpart.use.prefix=true;
    SET hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true;
    SET hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled =true;
    SET hive.cbo.enable=true;
    SET hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
    SET hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
    SET hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
    SET mapred.reduce.tasks = -1;
    SET hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size=2730;
    SET hive.auto.convert.join=true;
    SET hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask=true;
    SET hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size=405306368;
    SET hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
    SET hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
    SET hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
    SET mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps=0.8;


    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS X STORED AS PARQUET AS 
      SELECT a,
             b,
             c
        FROM A
      UNION ALL
      SELECT a,
             b,
             c
        FROM B
      UNION ALL
      SELECT a,
             b,
             c
        FROM C;
```

If I try to run the below query on Presto it shows that there is data.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM 
(
          SELECT a,
                 b,
                 c
            FROM A
          UNION ALL
          SELECT a,
                 b,
                 c
            FROM B
          UNION ALL
          SELECT a,
                 b,
                 c
            FROM C 
)Z;
```

Comment: Please check data is available on your table.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` when running on Tez runs in parallel and creates extra sub-directories in the table location (check what is inside table location). Try to add these configuration settings before reading the table to allow Hive to read subdirectories:

```
set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true; 
set mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
```

Your query is quite simple and runs on mappers-only each subquery writing it's own sub-directory and does not interfere with another one.

**Alternatively** you can force extra reducer stage by adding `distribute by` at the end or `order by` (will run slower), run UNION instead of UNION ALL, apply filter after union etc - it will create files in the table folder without subdirectories:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS X STORED AS PARQUET AS 
select * from 
(
      SELECT a,
             b,
             c
        FROM A
      UNION ALL
      SELECT a,
             b,
             c
        FROM B
      UNION ALL
      SELECT a,
             b,
             c
        FROM C
      )s distribute by a; --this will force reducer step
```

Comment: My underlying files are stored on S3. Would that cause any issue?

Comment: @Teja To avoid eventual consistency in S3 (read after delete) after re-loading this table, apply method which create less number of files. distribute by low cardinality column or for example `distribute by FLOOR(RAND()*100.0)%20` - it will create 20 equal files and will run 20 reducers in parallel on final reducer vertex. But if possible, apply first method with recursive irectories

Comment: What could be the issue leftjoin? I made sure DDL's are exactly the same and ran the above query. It produces zero rows. :(

Comment: How did you check the data was not loaded? I suppose select count(*) from table after load?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( UNION ALL QUERY ) in hive returns > 0 rows. I have checked in both presto and hive.